# What happens if I draw a big circle outside of the viewable region of the canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawing

For example

```
 canvas.drawCircle(x=10, y=10, veryBigRadius=1000000 , paint);
```

I my app, if I draw many things outside of the canvas, it seems use many memories and CPU time, so that it seems not responsible to user's actions. And do there is any framework/algorithm to filter/trim the graphic shapes to draw on the canvas?

Thanks for any suggestion!